# SharePoint 2010 Calendar Error when change Content Type

Tags: content-type, error, calendar

Recently a calendar was created in a Site Collection with a personal content type and a personal column. When I tried to save after adding a new event or modifying the event, I have the famous error an expected error was occurred.

My log file in the severity is Unexpected:

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object     �
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Applications.GroupBoard.WebControls.OverbookField.get_IsRecurrence()
>   �
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Applications.GroupBoard.WebControls.OverbookField.BuildSPItem()
>   �
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Applications.GroupBoard.WebControls.OverbookField.IsOverbook()
>   �
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Applications.GroupBoard.WebControls.OverbookField.Validate()
>   � System.Web.UI.Page.Validate()     �
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)     �
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)     �
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   Severity High:
>
> MetadataNavigationContext Page_InitComplete: No XsltListViewWebPart
>   was found on this
>   page[/sites/Sites/Lists/Calendar/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=Lists%2FCalendar&ContentTypeId=0x01003DA6D35AEEEB8C4AA5AC98EB36858C88&IsDlg=1].
>   Hiding key filters and downgrading tree functionality to legacy
>   ListViewWebPart(v3) level for this list.